# Definition of a p-value

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I'm studying [all statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441923225) by Wasserman and on page 156 he defines p-values:

> **10.11 Deﬁnition**. Suppose that for every $\alpha \in (0,1)$ we have a size $\alpha$ test with rejection region $R_{\alpha}$. Then,
>
> $$\text{p-value} = \inf\{\alpha: T(X^n)\in R _{\alpha}\}$$
>
> That is, the p-value is the smallest level at which we can reject
> $H_0$.

I've already seen some answers here to this definition in Wasserman book, but my question is more basic. I want to know what is this exponent $n$. What does $X^n$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate use of poorly-chosen notation.  Presumably, $X^n$ is intended to indicate a sample of size $n$; i.e., $X^n = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$, from which a test statistic defined by some function $T$ of the sample is calculated.  This notation is probably inherited from expressions like $\mathbb R^n$.  But for obvious reasons, one should probably avoid writing things this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This $X^n$ is fixed?

Comment: @user42912 In the frequentist viewpoint, the sample is a realization of random variables, so no.  $T$, being a test **statistic** is a function of random variables.